# How to check keys of key value pair inside mongodb structure

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb collection where objects are structured as such:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "history": [
    {
      "userid": 100,
      "myobjects": [{id, id1, id4}]
    },
    {
      "userid": 200,
      "myobjects": [{id2, id3, id5}]
    },
}
```

Goal: if my userid is 100, return an object that doesn't contain my userid in its history. I'm guessing it'd be some kind of "my userid not in keys of history field" but i'm not sure how to write that out. Here's my basic idea:

```
Collection.findOne(
  {
    in_progress : null, 
    history : {"$nin": myuserid } ???
  }
);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [MongoDB aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind" : "$history"
    },
    {
        "$match" : {
            "history.userid" : {
                "$ne" : 100
            }
        }
    },
    {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : "$id",
        "history" : {
            "$push" : "$history"
        }
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: I'm getting an "Collections.aggregate is not a function" error. Does aggregation only work in command line MongoDB operations, and perhaps not in Meteor / .js code?

Comment: Try adding the aggregate package for Meteor.
`meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate`